# Xcode 5 Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 error while validating

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I'm running into the `Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5` error:

[image: Error message]

I tried every solution suggested in the other questions but nothing works. To summarize:

I have the `Default-568h@2x.png` image with a size of 640 × 1136 in the root directory of the project, where `project_name.xcodeproj` is.

Following one advice, I added `Default.png` (640 × 1136) and `Default~iphone.png` (640 × 960) to the same directory. Didn't work.

I am using an asset catalog with the proper sizes in place.

Here's the strangest part: this is a version 1.1 of the application. I'm using the same .`xcodeproj` with the same images. It validated with no issues the first time, but now it doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using the image asset global to control if the image is correct, and see if there is the warning.

For the future is better using with last Xcode a storyboard screen:

[image]

To turn your app in universal mode:

add a storybord or using a StoryBorad in Auto Layout mode.

To use multiple storyboard you can use this in your AppDelegate inside a `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
#pragma mark - Universal storyboard.

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width *scale, result.height *scale);

        if(result.height <= 960){
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
            [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
        }
    }
```

You can add all resolution iPhone 4s / 5 (s/c) 6 and 6 Plus

In your `<AppName>-Prefix.pch` define all resolutions like this:

```
#define   IsIphone5     ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
#define   IsIphone4     ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )480 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Then call the function in your project, for example one scrollview for iPhone 4/5 and iPad:

```
- (void)spiegaScroll{

    if (IsIphone5){

    CGRect scrollFrame;
    scrollFrame.origin = myScroll.frame.origin;
    scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 568);
    spiega.frame = scrollFrame;
    [spiega setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1100)];
    myScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
    myScroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
    myScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;

    } else if (IsIphone4) {

        CGRect scrollFrame;
        scrollFrame.origin = myScroll.frame.origin;
        scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
        spiega.frame = scrollFrame;
        [spiega setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1100)];
        myScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        myScroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
        myScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;

    } else {

//the rest is iPad in this case

        CGRect scrollFrame;
        scrollFrame.origin = myScroll.frame.origin;
        scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(768, 1024);
        spiega.frame = scrollFrame;
        [spiega setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 2094)];
        myScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        myScroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
        myScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;
    }

}
```

Hope this help you for now or for your future apps ;)

Comment: Thanks @Jhon. I think it will be useful in the future but for now upgrading to xCode 6 did the trick.

Comment: I finish my post if you use Xcode 6 you can solve with the first part of my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check wheter the images are added to target files

Answer (score 0):

In your plist file set the value for your images in the icon set dictionary.

Comment: do you have an example how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue. finally i found solution from [Iphone 5 Launch Image Problem](https://github.com/Simbul/baker/issues/1201)

please make sure the 568h file is in PNG format? Also make sure that you provided support for iphone 5 for all your screens? Only adding Default-568h@2x.png is not gaurantee for iphone 5 support. You have to check for framing of all your view for iphone 3.5" and 4" device.

Comment: how do you mean "check for framing of all your views"? Obviously I made sure they look good for both sizes. Is there a formal standard, or criteria?

Comment: yup i know you have checked all, but if by mistake some views are missing to check framing. and for what you have asked for standard & criteria?

Comment: Do you have an example of something that was a problem and you fixed it? I'm still not sure what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the problem went away once I upgraded to xCode 6. The app validated with no issues.