# Can't submit app due to this issue "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 (Launch Image {320, 568})"

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, submit

I know this error has come up before, but most solutions have not worked for me and I don't know really what to do, so could someone take me step by step for a solution? Thanks!:

Hello, I have created an app and am blocked by this error as I am submitted it to the App Store after archiving:

Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5- New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .Iproj folder if you localize your launch images.

I have already put my images into the Base.Iproj folder and they are the correct sizes.

This is the code in my Info.plist:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
           <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
           <string>en</string>
           <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
           <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
           <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
           <string>(NOT SHOWING MY BUNDLE ID)</string>
           <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
           <string>6.0</string>
           <key>CFBundleName</key>
           <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
           <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
           <string>APPL</string>
           <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
           <string>1.0</string>
           <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
           <string>????</string>
           <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
           <string>1</string>
           <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
           <true/>
           <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
           <string>LaunchScreeniphone5.png</string>
           <key>UILaunchImageFile~iphone</key>
           <string>LaunchScreeniphone5.png</string>
           <key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
           <string>LaunchScreeniphone5.png</string>
           <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
           <string>Main</string>
           <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
               <array>
                  <string>armv7</string>
                  <string>gamekit</string>
               </array>
           <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
                <array>
                   <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                </array>
           <key>UILaunchImages</key>
                <array>
                   <dict>
                      <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
                      <string>7.0</string>
                      <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
                      <string>Default-568h@2x </string>
                      <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
                      <string>Portrait</string>
                      <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
                      <string>{320, 568}</string>
                  </dict>
              </array>
         </dict>
 </plist>
```

However, another problem is that not all of that stuff is showing in my Info.plist in the project!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

See the following already posted answers of the question of this type:: i think You can get your required answers from these...
[invalid binary for iPhone5 (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780432/xcode-error-while-validation-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5)

[invalid binary for iPhone5 (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087160/xcode-5-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-error-while-validating)

[invalid binary  for iPhone5 (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850903/invalid-binary-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-as-of-may-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <string>Default-568h@2x </string>
```

I believe there is a trailing space in your image name mate.
I also strongly recommand using xcassets for managing LaunchImages and benefit from the upcoming [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3)!